# Can someone flying with winged boots/boots of flying carry someone?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, flight

Can a person with winged boots carry another medium size creature, and if so, would it require any checks?

I found this info in the DMG, page 214:

> #### Winged Boots
>
> Wondrous item, uncommon (requires attunement
>
> While you wear these boots, you have a flying speed equal to your walking speed. You can use the boots to fly for up to 4 hours, all at once or in several shorter flights, each one using a minimum of 1 minute from the duration. If you are flying when the duration expires, you descend at a rate of 30 feet per round until you land.
>
> The boots regain 2 hours of flying capability for every 12 hours they aren't in use.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since nothing about weight is mentioned and the boots give you flying speed equal to your walking speed, I would assume that the regular carrying capacity rules are in effect (page 176 of PHB). You can carry 15 times your strength (including your equipment etc), or push, drag or lift 30 times your own weight. If doing the latter and the thing you move is heavier than your carrying capacity, you will have your speed reduced to 5 feet.

It might feel a bit silly that winged boots are affected by your strength, but I think it's RAW.

Comment: Winged boots are already affected by creature's walking speed so it does not feel silly for me to imagine them to only support someones ankles but still require him to actually walk in the air. No one is falling down due to too much weight here, right? So walking is walking.

Comment: +1'd this is exactly how I ruled in my game. The boots don't do the flying by themselves, the synergy between magic of the item + the user (via attunement) give out the final effect. Then it is obvious that a stronger host will grant more lifting power to the boots. Magical Metaphysics 101 as I learned in the Silverymoon academy...

Comment: Pushing or dragging implies the thing is still on the ground, so that would have very limited usefulness while flying, unless you're very close to the ground or the thing is tall. And lifting means not moving at all, though again I guess you could fly up in the air and then lift something off the ground if it was tall enough.

Comment: @Zeus Not really. One could try to push a flying object, for example, that is just hovering in place or somehow levitating.

Comment: @T.Sar That's true, good point.