# Can you carry someone while levitating?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, flight, encumbrance

The [***levitate spell***](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/levitate) targets:

> One creature or loose object of your choice that you can see within range \$[\dots]\$ that weighs up to 500 pounds.

If you're airborne from casting ***levitate*** on yourself, could you then pick up another creature?

Is the answer different if your total weight is greater than or less than 500 pounds?

Would the weight of the second creature also need to fit within your carrying capacity as described [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110716/can-someone-flying-with-winged-boots-boots-of-flying-carry-someone)?

If your passenger was unwilling, would you simply need to have successfully grappled them?

Comment: Related: "[How much can you carry using the fly spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76938)" and "[How much weight can an Aarakocra carry when flying?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76758)" and "[Can someone flying with winged boots/boots of flying carry someone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110716)" and "[How do I grapple/drag an unconscious ally? Does he make a contested check against mine?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125691)" and "[What are the rules around picking up and carrying bodies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103496)"

Comment: Also related (to the 500-pound limit in particular): "[Is a spell suppressed or removed when the target temporarily becomes invalid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133379)"

Comment: I'm unsure if this question is asking too many separate things in one question... "Can you pick up a creature while levitating? (The weight part is wrapped into that nicely though)." "Does carrying capacity affect the ability to fly?" "Does the willingness of a creature affect the ability to pick them up?" These feel a bit separate to me though I *do* see the interconnectedness as well... I voted for close as "Needs More Focus" but it's not a clear choice for me; especially when some of them are at least partially answered elsewhere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This is my personal opinion which seems to work with players**

I've always ruled the spell effect as being able to levitate a creature or object that weights 500 pounds or less and that's it as far the spell's weight limitation goes.

Whether a PC can carry someone or something else depends on their ability to hold onto the weight they want to carry. Just because you're currently under the effects of Levitate doesn't mean you can personally carry more. That extra load requires you to hold it so the character's strength score is going to come into play.

Alternatively, you can add the (commonsense) restriction that if the total load being lifted exceeds 500 pounds the spell ends, with whatever effect the DM thinks is relevant happening e.g. fall to the ground, drift down, etc.

So, a PC under the effect of Levitate, to my mind, can't say "I want to carry up that 300 pound boulder and drop it." unless they can personally carry that weight normally.

I've found that most players I've played with agree with this approach as practical and still useful in game.

**Carrying an unwilling target**

For this I would rule that a standard grapple check is required. There is nothing mechanically different about grabbing someone while under the effects of Levitate compared to grabbing them normally. The effects of the grapple are still the same as are their options for breaking free so I see no reason to further complicate it.

Comment: Perfect answer...  aside from the type of "fro" instead of "for".  Too small a change for me to edit for you.

Note:  Keep the ruling consistent.  If one character or NPC can carry someone whilst levitating, so can everyone else.  MAYBE bend the rules a bit allowing for more load during a dramatically apropraite moment, but always in favour of a PC when a player has a "cunning plan".

Comment: If they then want to "climb" along a wall (remember thats the only way they can move as per the spell description), I'd absolutely demand an acrobatics check if theyre also carrying someone